# Plotting a 3D gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, data-visualization, multivariate-analysis

I was wondering what is a good way to visualize a 3D Gaussian distributions.

Suppose I have a mu(1x3) rowvector and a covar(3x3) matrix.

I know I can use the basic visual formula and get the density of a 1x3 point for this distribution, but since visualizing the whole density is impossible given that I would have to jump to the fourth dimension, what would be a good way to visualize the distribution?

Pairwise plotting of the 3D parts of the Gaussian maybe? So plot (x1-x2),(x1-x3),(x2-x3) given their respective covars individually?

That would serve as the projection of the distribution in the reduced dimension space. Any other alternatives for visualization?

Cheers,
Panos.

Comment: I once plotted this in a 3D scatter plot with points equidistantly scattered and the marker diameter proportional to the density function value at this point. I thought that looked pretty good.